# How to package JMeter with Jar Bundler on Mac

Tags: jmeter, jarbundler

I'm unable to use "Jar Bundler" on mac to create JMeter.app from ApacheJMeter.jar, I was wondering if anyone else had previous experience with configuring this tool? The problem for me seems to be that the lib folder being searched is set to an incorrect base path:

```
org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver: JMeter home directory was detected as: /Users/username/Applications/JMeter.app/Contents/Resources
```

I looked here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html

But no matter how I configured any of the said properties, the logs looked the same.

Answer (score 1):

The real trick is making sure the bin and lib folders can be found.  The only jar file you will need to add is ApacheJMeter.jar.  Look in the bin/jmeter script for additional properties to put into the properties tab of the Jar Bundler. The java arguments in the bin/jmeter script should be copied into the VM Options field. Check Set Working Directory to Inside Application Package. Now create application. Open up the .app folder that was just created and copy the bin and lib folders into the Resources directory.  Done.

Comment: ```[LaunchRunner Error] The main class "org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver" could not be found.```

Comment: Did you check Set Working Directory to Inside Application Package option?